# Why do app gets stopped unexpectedly everytime using any code

Tags: java, android

#### My apologies

Hi, I am a newbie to the advance level programming. I have been working around with the basics and the syntax of the language.

#### I have searched enough

The problem I am having is, that each time, I write the code to handle the events in my App, it gets stopped. I have tried following step by step coding of the video from Treehouse tutorial of using the `onClick` and I have tried to follow the Android's official developer documents too. I have also looked into the codes at some sites (including and specially Stack Overflow).

#### All in vain

But each time I run the code, app works and when it has to execute the methods and functions, it gives me an alert saying App (Number Converter) stopped Unexpectedly. I am creating an app to convert the numbers from and to the 4 number systems, decimal, binary, octal and hexadecimal.

But, I am not able to get to the point why and why every time I write the code that is same, doesn't work and app stops.

#### Here is the code I am trying:

```
Button frmDeciToOct = (Button) findViewById(R.id.fromDecToOct);
/* here is the method that is the onClick */
frmDeciToBin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {            
   @Override
   public void onClick(View v) {
     /* getting the edit text view */
     EditText edtTxt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.decimalValue);
     /* to string... */
     String value = edtTxt.getText().toString();
     /* conversion to int, I saw this method on SO's answer */
     int value2 = Integer.valueOf(value);
     /* createBinOfDeci is a method, I will post its code after this */
     String result = createBinOfDeci(value2);
     /* get the text view */
     TextView txtView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.fromDeciRes);
     /* set the text as a result */
     txtView.setText(result);
   }
});
```

#### Here is the code for my method `createBinOfDeci()`:

```
public String createBinOfDeci (int deci) {
    String result = "";
    result = Integer.toBinaryString(deci);
    return result;
}
```

The only thing that I am getting is that, I am using Windows and it gets crashed due to less RAM amount here! I am truly out of guesses and answers. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: can you please post logcat?

Comment: Use LogCat to examine the Java stack trace associated with your crash. If you have difficulty in interpreting what the stack trace means, edit your question and paste it in.

Comment: the first thing you need to learn about, debugging-wise, is reading the logcat and the exception stacktrace resulting of the error. Assuming you code using Eclipse, there is a View that is called logcat  (you can view that using the `adb logcat` command in a shell, too), in which appear the logs of your app. When an exception is thrown, not caught, and crashes the app, there will be a Log, with the stack trace, telling you exactly where to look for the error.

Comment: @CommonsWare, Ok wait I will try to read the stack trace and notice if that helps me out :)

Comment: @CommonsWare you were right! I should have checked the LogCat first. The error was the value ...

Answer (score 0):

As @CommonsWare suggested, to check the LogCat, and I saw that it showed me a few errors.

[image]

Which was a clear sign of saying: The values are not correctly matching up.

Then I came up to the point, that the values weren't actually filled. They were empty, and I was running the code on a `null` hehe.

I just added the value and it worked!

Thanks guys (for the LogCat suggestion).